# char* return type acting strange

Tags: c++

I am using visual studio.
The following code will print nonsense in the console.

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    
    namespace tools {
        char* slice_to(const char arr[],char term) {
            char tulem[1000];
            char(*tul)[1000] = &tulem;
            int i = -1;
            do{
                i++;
                tulem[i] = (arr[i] == term) ? '\0' : arr[i];
            } while (arr[i]!=term);
            return *tul;
        }
    };
    
    
    int main() {
        std::cout<<tools::slice_to("This is a test!", '\0');
    }
```

But if I print something before calling the function it works fine. Why is that?
The following code prints what I would expect:

```
#include <iostream>


namespace tools {
    char* slice_to(const char arr[],char term) {
        char tulem[1000];
        char(*tul)[1000] = &tulem;
        int i = -1;
        do{
            i++;
            tulem[i] = (arr[i] == term) ? '\0' : arr[i];
        } while (arr[i]!=term);
        return *tul;
    }
};


int main() {
    std::cout << "Bruh\n";
    std::cout<<tools::slice_to("This is a test!", '\0');
}
```

Also using the `printf` function outputs the correct result.

Comment: Functions "conditionally" working is a sign of undefined behavior.`tulem` is a temporary object, that gets destroyed at the end of `slice_to`. So you cannot return a pointer to it and expect it to still be there.

Comment: Is `char(*tul)[1000] = &tulem;... return *tul;` some kind of attempt to not return `tulem`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to `cout` a local variable that is out-of-scope once the `slice_to` returns. As you're returning a ptr, no copy of the underlying data is being done - it's a pointer to memory that is no longer valid. As it's on the stack, it may not be overwritten (hence you're able to access the values under the address) but this is an error.

Try changing the return type of `slice_to` to `std::string` that will manage the underlying memory and will create a temporary object when the function exits - that should do just fine.

Comment: If you want to avoid std::string then you need to pass a character buffer in to to your function then copy all the characters including the null terminator into that buffer.  If you do that and get it working. Then add code to receive the length of the buffer passed in as a parameter and stop copying characters if it fills up and put a null character at the end. Or use a return value that can indicate success or failure.